# Automate running several projects at once in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I have multiple spreadsheet bound projects, and I want once in a while run all of them together. Is there a possibility to automate this, as I do not want open each project and run it manually. And as I understand I cannot create installable timed triggers, as I have more than 20, and I am not collaborating with anyone.

My vision - is to create a standalone project where I loop through all the projects using their project/script key(id)s. **I only do not know if this is possible, and if yes how do I code this - a call of a script knowing its scriptid?**

Comment: It is best to ask a question for each project and provide some details and possibly code for each.  There's probably a way to accomplish something close to what you want.

Comment: This is possible by using Google Apps Script API. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to provide a proper response to the question, I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section.

Yes, it's possible to run several projects at once with Apps Script with method [scripts.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run)

You can use this [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#javascript) to have an idea on how to do it with Apps Script.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute) that @Ruben shared above has specific details to accomplish what you're looking for. Make sure to check the requirements and also the [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#limitations) to check if the projects you're trying to run meet the requirements.